# Is it possible to separate a triple integral into a difference of two triple integral?

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

Is it possible to do this subtraction ?

$\int\limits_{z = 0}^{z = \frac{b}{a}} {\int\limits_{x = 0}^{x = \infty } {\int\limits_{y = \frac{a}{x}}^{y = \frac{b}{{xz}}} {f\left( y \right)f\left( x \right)f\left( z \right)dydxdz = } } } \int\limits_{z = 0}^{z = \frac{b}{a}} {\int\limits_{x = 0}^{x = \infty } {\int\limits_{y = 0}^{y = \frac{b}{{xz}}} {f\left( y \right)f\left( x \right)f\left( z \right)dydxdz} } }  - \int\limits_{z = 0}^{z = \frac{b}{a}} {\int\limits_{x = 0}^{x = \infty } {\int\limits_{y = 0}^{y = \frac{a}{x}} {f\left( y \right)f\left( x \right)f\left( z \right)dydxdz} } } $

where $a,b,f\left( y \right),f\left( x \right),f\left( z \right) \geqslant 0$ and ${f\left( y \right),f\left( x \right),f\left( z \right)}$ are all decaying exponential function.

If it wrong then why ?
Thank you very much ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what does "decaying exponential function" exactly mean, but one can claim that you are right if **all the integrals converges**. From the Linearity of integrals, we have:
\begin{aligned}
&\quad \int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{a}}{\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\int\limits_{\frac{a}{x}}^{\frac{b}{xz}}{f\left( y \right) f\left( x \right) f\left( z \right) dydxdz=}}}\int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{a}}{\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\left( \int\limits_{\frac{a}{x}}^{\frac{b}{xz}}{f\left( y \right) dy} \right) f\left( x \right) f\left( z \right) dxdz}}
\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{a}}{\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\left( \int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{xz}}{f\left( y \right) dy-\int\limits_0^{\frac{a}{x}}{f\left( y \right) dy}} \right) f\left( x \right) f\left( z \right) dxdz}}
\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{a}}{\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\left( \int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{xz}}{f\left( y \right) dy} \right) f\left( x \right) f\left( z \right) dxdz}}-\int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{a}}{\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\left( +\int\limits_0^{\frac{a}{x}}{f\left( y \right) dy} \right) f\left( x \right) f\left( z \right) dxdz}}
\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{a}}{\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{xz}}{f\left( y \right) f\left( x \right) f\left( z \right) dydxdz}}}-\int\limits_0^{\frac{b}{a}}{\int\limits_0^{\infty}{\int\limits_0^{\frac{a}{x}}{f\left( y \right) f\left( x \right) f\left( z \right) dydxdz}}}
\end{aligned}
As desired.